# Problem with running genymotion in KDE desktop

Tags: 14.04, android, kde

1- I have a problem in running genymotion in KDE Plasma desktop in ubuntu 14.04 but it   works in default ubuntu desktop corectly!

It gives me an error like this:

```
    linux@younes:~$ ~/genymotion/genymotion
    Logging activities to file: /home/linux/.Genymobile/genymotion.log
    Aborted (core dumped)
    linux@younes:~$
```

please help me

Comment: will you please attach the log file content

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This one helped me try it,

Installing the libs:

```
apt-get install libxi-dev libxmu-dev
```

Moving the Qt libs inside the Genymotion installation directory
Code:

```
mkdir QtLibs && mv *Qt*.so* QtLibs
```

Try to read what log says.

Comment: how did you know?

Comment: know what... ??

Comment: I mean how did you know it need to Qt libs ?

Comment: I guessed it will need Qt libs because the problem is popular... : )

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and just solved it. I already had `LibQt*` files inside the `genymotion` folder. Then I deleted all the `libQt*` files from the folder. Now it works like a charm. The genymotion development team has also said to delete these files.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I performed the following steps:

1. Installing the libs:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libxi-dev libxmu-dev libqt4-webkit libqt4-svg
   ```
2. Now, go to Genymotion installation directory, then move the Qt libs:

   ```
   mkdir QtLibs && mv *Qt*.so* QtLibs
   ```