# Genymotion stop working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, genymotion

After allocating my system (Ubuntu 16.04) in data center, suddenly my Genymotion stopped working by following error:

```
Logging activities to file: /home/*/.Genymobile/genymotion.log (noting logged here)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

So I re-install it, but still same problem....
So I checked the Virtualbox by following:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv status
sudo: /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: command not found
```

So I came up with uninstalling both and installing them again. but the problem is still exists

Here is what I have done:

installing Virtualbox and related package:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.1_5.1.16-1138411~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb (downloaded from virtualbox.org)

Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-5.1.
(Reading database ... 246386 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack virtualbox-5.1_5.1.16-113841~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-5.1 (5.1.16-113841~Ubuntu~xenial) ...
Setting up virtualbox-5.1 (5.1.16-113841~Ubuntu~xenial) ...
addgroup: The group `vboxusers' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu17) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...

$ sudo apt-get install -f

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 162 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt-get install dkms

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dkms
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 162 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/66.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 265 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package dkms.
(Reading database ... 247164 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.3_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up dkms (2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.3) ...

$ sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/s
scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n vboxdrv)

$ sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv status
sudo: /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: command not found

$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-4.10.0-30-generic is already the newest version (4.10.0-30.34~16.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 162 not upgraded.
```

Install and run Genymotion:

```
$ ./genymotion-2.8.1_x64.bin -d /opt/

    Installing for all users.        
    Installing to folder [/opt/genymotion]. Are you sure [y/n] ? y      
    - Trying to find VirtualBox toolset .................... OK (Valid version of VirtualBox found: 5.1.16r113841)
    - Extracting files ..................................... OK (Extract into: [/opt/genymotion])
    - Installing launcher icon ............................. OK
    Installation done successfully.        
    You can now use these tools from [/opt/genymotion]:
     - genymotion
     - genymotion-shell
     - gmtool

$ /opt/genymotion/genymotion
Logging activities to file: /home/*/.Genymobile/genymotion.log
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have tried following, but the error still is available:

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential module-assistant     
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.1ubuntu2).
module-assistant is already the newest version (0.11.8).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 162 not upgraded.

$ sudo m-a prepare
Getting source for kernel version: 4.10.0-30-generic
Kernel headers available in /usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-30-generic
Creating symlink...
apt-get install build-essential 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.1ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 162 not upgraded.
Done!

$ sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
sudo: /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: command not found
```

here is the result of `/etc/init.d/virtualbox status`:

```
virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/virtualbox; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-08-09 23:51:09 IRDT; 12h ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

Aug 09 23:51:09 *-G31M-ES2C virtualbox[31835]:  * Loading VirtualBox kern...
Aug 09 23:51:09 *-G31M-ES2C virtualbox[31835]:  * No suitable module for ...
Aug 09 23:51:09 *-G31M-ES2C virtualbox[31835]:    ...fail!
Aug 09 23:51:09 *-G31M-ES2C systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Control proc...1
Aug 09 23:51:09 *-G31M-ES2C systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox ....
Aug 09 23:51:09 *-G31M-ES2C systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Unit entered....
Aug 09 23:51:09 *-G31M-ES2C systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Failed with ....
Aug 10 00:04:22 *-G31M-ES2C systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: VirtualBox Linux ke....
Aug 10 00:08:51 *-G31M-ES2C systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: VirtualBox Linux ke....
Aug 10 00:23:30 *-G31M-ES2C systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: VirtualBox Linux ke....
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

I just reboot the system and here is the result again:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/virtualbox status
● virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/virtualbox; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2017-08-10 12:15:37 IRDT; 4min 14s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1107 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/virtualbox start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 10 12:15:37 *-G31M-ES2C systemd[1]: Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux k....
Aug 10 12:15:37 *-G31M-ES2C systemd[1]: Started LSB: VirtualBox Linux ke....
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.

$ opt/genymotion/genymotion
Logging activities to file: /home/*/.Genymobile/genymotion.log (still empty)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I found That following command is same as `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup|status` ([reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852590/failed-installation-of-virtualbox-5-1-on-ubuntu-16-04?rq=1))

```
 /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup|status
```

here is the result:

```
VirtualBox kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) are loaded
```

I also try solution in [Problem with running genymotion in KDE desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525419/problem-with-running-genymotion-in-kde-desktop) but I get following error:

```
Logging activities to file: /home/*/.Genymobile/genymotion.log (noting logged here)
    Aborted (core dumped)
```

and here is the *.log file:

```
Aug 11 01:40:08 [genymotion] [fatal] This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

Also I check library needed by Qt as stated in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688442/install-genymotion-2-6-0-on-ubuntu-15-04), but noting listed in result, so all necessary lib is available.

**Edit 1**

I [find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179998/where-to-search-for-the-core-file-generated-by-the-crash-of-a-linux-application) that system with `systemd` dumped core to `/var/lib/systemd/coredump/` so first I install `coredumpctl` and then run `Genymotion` to create core dump. Follow instruction [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65110/no-more-coredumps-after-migrating-to-systemd/65111#65111) to create dump.core, here is the result:

```
$ coredumpctl dump 9808 --output /home/*/genymotion.core     

    PID: 9808(genymotion)
           UID: 1000 (*)
           GID: 1000 (*)
        Signal: 6 (ABRT)
     Timestamp: Fri 2017-08-11 12:37:29 IRDT (4min 58s ago)
  Command Line: /opt/genymotion/genymotion
    Executable: /opt/genymotion/genymotion
 Control Group: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-c2.scope
          Unit: session-c2.scope
         Slice: user-1000.slice
       Session: c2
     Owner UID: 1000 (*)
       Boot ID: f572250f03be48d9aa9facf22d0ffd0a
    Machine ID: *******
      Hostname: *-G31M-ES2C
      Coredump: /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.genymotion.1000.f572250f03be48d9aa9facf22d0ffd0a.9808.1502438849000000000000.xz
       Message: Process 9808 (genymotion) of user 1000 dumped core.

                Stack trace of thread 9808:
                #0  0x00007f86f96c2428 __GI_raise (libc.so.6)
                #1  0x00007f86f96c402a __GI_abort (libc.so.6)
                #2  0x00000000004b6fb7 n/a (genymotion)
                #3  0x00007f86fa74f468 n/a (libQt5Core.so.5)
                #4  0x00007f86fa750f69 _ZNK14QMessageLogger5fatalEPKcz (libQt5Core.so.5)
                #5  0x00007f86fac80e99 _ZN22QGuiApplicationPrivate25createPlatformIntegrationEv (libQt5Gui.so.5)
                #6  0x00007f86fac80ecd _ZN22QGuiApplicationPrivate21createEventDispatcherEv (libQt5Gui.so.5)
                #7  0x00007f86fa9487e6 _ZN16QCoreApplication4initEv (libQt5Core.so.5)
                #8  0x00007f86fa948856 _ZN16QCoreApplicationC1ER23QCoreApplicationPrivate (libQt5Core.so.5)
                #9  0x00007f86fac82cc9 _ZN15QGuiApplicationC1ER22QGuiApplicationPrivate (libQt5Gui.so.5)
                #10 0x00007f86fa18ebcd _ZN12QApplicationC2ERiPPci (libQt5Widgets.so.5)
                #11 0x0000000000438c53 n/a (genymotion)
                #12 0x000000000042373e n/a (genymotion)
                #13 0x00007f86f96ad830 __libc_start_main (libc.so.6)
                #14 0x0000000000429739 n/a (genymotion)
More than one entry matches, ignoring rest.
```

and then run folllowing as @kenorb said:

```
$ gdb -c genymotion.core

GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5) 7.11.1
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
[New LWP 9808]
Core was generated by `/opt/genymotion/genymotion'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  0x00007f86f96c2428 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f86f96c2428 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007f86f96c402a in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000000000020 in ?? ()
#3  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x00007f86f96c2428 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x00007f86f96c402a in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x0000000000000020 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
```

**Edit 2**

I have remove builtin qt in Genymotion, and check available qt in my system:

```
$ qtchooser -list-versions
4
5
default
qt4-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt4
qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt5
```

but it still failed to start Genymotion.

I also install qt-5.9.1 by downloading `qt-unified-linux-x64-3.0.0-online` from [here](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/) but it doesn't list when I run `qtchooser -list-versions`. (no newer version was available), how should I force Genymotion work with this?

**Edit 3**

The solution didn't work for me I came up with reinstalling the operating system. Now all the thing is ok. but After rebooting system Genymotion failed again.

Comment: Your reinstallation worked, what you want to look at now is `/home/zahra/.Genymobile/genymotion.log`

Comment: It's still empty!

Comment: In Genymotion installation [guide](https://docs.genymotion.com/Content/01_Get_Started/Installation.htm) it said that : Make sure that the `dkms` package is installed and that it compiles VirtualBox kernel modules each time a new kernel update is available. But `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv status` not working in mine

Comment: The ubuntu version doesn't have vboxdrv, you need the [virtualbox.org](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) version for that.

Comment: I added `/etc/init.d/virtualbox status` result

Comment: @Ziazis Should I install another version off `virtualbox`?

Comment: Yes, use for genymotion the virtualbox.org version.

Comment: I have download the virtualbox-5.1_5.1.16-1138411~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb from the virtualbox.org. As my country IP is filtered I couldn't install it by apt-get, and if I run anti-filter my access to the server is lost .... Is there any way to install the correct virtualbox?

Comment: If you have the .deb package you can install it via `apt install virtualbox*.deb`

Comment: Before I installed it using `dpkg`,  but when I try apt it give me an error which I add it to Question, where can I find proper .deb

Comment: You can also use `dpkg -i <packagename>`

Comment: Before I have installed `virtualbox-5.1_5.1.16-1138411~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb` using `dpkg - i` does this `.deb` file note working with Genymotion? could you suggest me the correct `.deb`

Comment: @user3933607 Re: `Aborted (core dumped)`. Can you post the `gdb` backtrace? So find the core dump file and run `gdb -c dump.core`, then run: `bt` or `bt full`.

Comment: where the `dump.core` is located since `gdb -c` said `no such file or directory`

Comment: @kenorb, I add `bt` and `bt full` to the question.

Comment: @user3933607 This sounds like a bug in Genymotion it-self, can you report the problem to their support and see what they'll reply?

Comment: @kenorb It work fine before I move the system to data center, there I install x11vnc server to remotely access the system, the app open once there (with out running any virtual devices), I think Its okey with out connected monitor, but when I run the app on my system It didn't run. Thanks

Comment: I report the problem to Genymotion support.

Comment: @kenorb Genymotion support didn't answer me yet, I would be grateful if anyone could help me find the issue. or have any suggestion.

Comment: @user3933607 Could you upgrade Qt5 libs (libQt5Core)? Which version you've currently installed? You can use [`apt-file`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31755542/55075) to find to which package it belongs to.

Comment: I edit that command in question. PS: I should use `/sbin/rcvboxdrv setup|status` instead

Answer (score 0):

Your crash seems to be related to [Qt framework](https://wiki.qt.io/About_Qt) (`libQt5Gui.so.5`). These are the revelant lines:

```
   Stack trace of thread 9808:
    #0  0x00007f86f96c2428 __GI_raise (libc.so.6)
    #1  0x00007f86f96c402a __GI_abort (libc.so.6)
    #2  0x00000000004b6fb7 n/a (genymotion)
    #3  0x00007f86fa74f468 n/a (libQt5Core.so.5)
    #4  0x00007f86fa750f69 _ZNK14QMessageLogger5fatalEPKcz (libQt5Core.so.5)
    #5  0x00007f86fac80e99 _ZN22QGuiApplicationPrivate25createPlatformIntegrationEv (libQt5Gui.so.5)
    #6  0x00007f86fac80ecd _ZN22QGuiApplicationPrivate21createEventDispatcherEv (libQt5Gui.so.5)
    #7  0x00007f86fa9487e6 _ZN16QCoreApplication4initEv (libQt5Core.so.5)
    #8  0x00007f86fa948856 _ZN16QCoreApplicationC1ER23QCoreApplicationPrivate (libQt5Core.so.5)
    #9  0x00007f86fac82cc9 _ZN15QGuiApplicationC1ER22QGuiApplicationPrivate (libQt5Gui.so.5)
    #10 0x00007f86fa18ebcd _ZN12QApplicationC2ERiPPci (libQt5Widgets.so.5)
```

[Searching for `_ZNK14QMessageLogger5fatalEPKcz`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=_ZNK14QMessageLogger5fatalEPKcz) gives some similar issues with this library.

Please see the following bug:

- [FS#47801 - [qt] plasma does not start after upgrade to qt5*5.5.1-9](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/47801)

which suggest this problem happens in Qt 5.5.1-9, however not in 5.5.1-7 (or -8). So you could try to upgrade or downgrade your Qt.

Another workaround to try is to remove `/var/lib/sddm/.cache` file as per this [comment](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/47801#comment142947).

Ideally if you could upgrade your Qt to the [latest available version](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.9/), otherwise try to install it manually (5.9.2 or above) in order to replace your faulty `libQt5Gui.so.5` file library, or build from the [source code](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt5.git/).

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try all. Since I try (solution here)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688442/install-genymotion-2-6-0-on-ubuntu-15-04] I think Qt lib are okey.

Comment: there is no `/var/lib/sddm/` directory in my system and also the latest version I found is 5.9.1. still have problem. (I edit the question and add what I have done)

Comment: @user3933607 You can try to build from the [source code](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt5.git/tree/README), or just wait for the new release in hope it's going to fix that bug/crash.

Comment: I flow http://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git but when I run `git checkout 5.9.2` I get following error `error: pathspec '5.9.2' did not match any file(s) known to git.` I ran `ldd` against the `libqxcb.so` library. [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=03456233102853175330) is the result. how can I change it to `5.9.1` the latest available version which I installed.

Comment: @user3933607 Tag `v5.9.2` [doesn't exist yet](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt5.git/refs/tags), so try [`5.9` branch](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt5.git/log/) which has the recent changes.

Comment: I try installing Qt `v5.9.1` but it didn't compiled correctly. Now I came up with uninstalling all Qt vesrion listed by `qtchooser` but I didn't find the correct way of clearing them.

Comment: Finally could Convinced data center administrator that the problem caused by lack of monitor connectivity. Do you have any Idea about why this happen?

Comment: @user3933607 Is your system [virtualized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/779723/55075)? Maybe that's the case.

Comment: only for monitor I used to use x11vnc.

Comment: @user3933607 Please re-read the question, whether your Linux is dedicated or virtualized. Basically paste output of this: `dmidecode -s system-product-name` or `dmidecode | egrep -i 'manufacturer|product'` command.

Comment: It is dedicated, the output to second is: `Manufacturer: System manufacturer
 Product Name: System Product Name
 Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
 Product Name: P8B75-V
 Manufacturer: Chassis Manufacture
 Manufacturer: Intel
 Manufacturer: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
 Manufacturer: Kingston
 Manufacturer: Kingston
 Manufacturer: 8313
 Manufacturer: 859B`